# Error cargando XML failed to load external entity

Tags: php, xml, iis

Buen día, estoy trabajando con rss de google news y acceder a los rss como xml con php7 y iis7,
Estoy utilizando simplexml_load_file pero no me funciona y me pone como salida.

> Error cargando XML failed to load external entity

este es mi codigo

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$sxe = simplexml_load_file($feed_url);
if ($sxe === false) {
    echo "Error cargando XML\n";
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo "\t", $error->message;
    }
}
```

lo estaba trabajando con php 5 y si me funcionaba con este codigo

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($feed_url);
foreach ($xml as $value) {            
        foreach ($value->item as $lue) {
          $title = $lue->title;
          $link = $lue->link;
          $description = $lue->description;
          $author = "Google";
          $pubdate = $lue->pubDate;
          $variablePHP1 = $nombre.'+'.$title.'+'.$pubdate;

          $query_insert = "INSERT INTO Publicaciones (Alias_Publicaciones,Clave,Nombre,title, link, description, author , pubdate, grupo1, grupo2, grupo3,url) values ('$variablePHP1','$clave','$nombre','$title','$link','$description','$author','$pubdate', '$gpo1', '$gpo2', '$gpo3', '$url')";
          $cons_insert= sqlsrv_query($connMI,$query_insert)or die (print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }                              
      }
```

con php 7 hice lo mismo pero no me hace nada $feed_url es mi url del rss

Espero puedan ayudarme gracias